# Mismatch problem with textbox and label! vb6

Tags: validation, textbox, vb6, label, currency

[image]I have tried to change the code but it didnt works.
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CTcash_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 13 Then
        bill = Val(CTcash.Text - CLtotaloutput.Caption)
        If Val(bill) > 0 Then
            Change.CLchange.Caption = Val(bill)
            Change.CLchange.Caption = Format(bill, "Rp\. ###,###,###.-")
            Change.Show
        End If
        If Val(bill) < 0 Then
            MsgBox "Not Enough Money", vbOKOnly, "Invalid"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The highlighted code

```
bill = Val(CTcash.Text - CLtotaloutput.Caption)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@John Eason is correct.  You also do not have to use `Val` on `bill` since it is already an integer.  And you are not doing anything if bill is 0 but this could be fine based on your requirements.

```
Private Sub CTcash_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 13 Then
        bill = Val(CTcash.Text) - Val(CLtotaloutput.Caption)
        If bill > 0 Then ' Note that when bill is 0 nothing happens but that might be fine
            'Change.CLchange.Caption = bill 'Not sure why this is needed but it may be
            Change.CLchange.Caption = Format(bill, "Rp\. ###,###,###.-")
            Change.Show
        End If
        If bill < 0 Then
            MsgBox "Not Enough Money", vbOKOnly, "Invalid"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I think a better approach would be to use a `Select Case` statement.

```
Private Sub CTcash_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 13 Then
        bill = Val(CTcash.Text) - Val(CLtotaloutput.Caption)

        Select Case True
            Case bill > 0 
               Change.CLchange.Caption = Format(bill, "Rp\. ###,###,###.-")
               Change.Show 
            Case bill < 0
               MsgBox "Not Enough Money", vbOKOnly, "Invalid"
            Case Else
               ' Do nothing - this documents that this is done on purpose
        End Select
     
    End If
End Sub
```

You can use `IsNumeric` function to check if the inputs are numeric and parse accordingly.  Use the `Right` function to remove any non-numbers from the left side.  For example, `Right("$123", Len("$123") - 1)` will remove the leading `$`.

To strip all non-numerical values from a string:

```
Dim ResultString As String
myString = "aaa34BB12,000xcv9.9zz"

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Len(myString)
    myChar = Mid(myString, i, 1)
    If IsNumeric(myChar) = True Then
        ResultString = ResultString + myChar
    End If
Next

MsgBox ResultString
```

Note that this may cause an issue with decimal amounts since 1.23 will before 123.  Not something you want.  Try using the `CCur` function.  I have never used it myself but it might be exactly what you want.

Source:  https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?437526-RESOLVED-Removing-non-numeric-chars-from-a-string&p=2686411&viewfull=1#post2686411

Comment: Your code seems to be VB.Net, not VB6 as the Q is tagged

Comment: It's VB6 since I ran it in Visual studio 6.

Comment: Sorry, no. `OrElse`, for example, is not a VB6 construct

Comment: You are right.  I thought you meant the answer example with the `Val` usage.  The last code I just copied from the vbforum example, hence the link, as an example of what can be done to remove non-numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Both CTcash.Text and CLTotaloutput.Caption are text strings so you can't subtract them directly. Try:

```
bill = Val(CTcash.text) - Val(CLtotaloutput.Caption)
```

You really should ensure that both strings are numerical first though!

Comment: This is correct but `Val` will parse out only the integers and return 0 if there are none or they are at the end of the line.  There will be no error if the strings are not numerical.

Comment: @eglease That's why I added my last sentence!

Comment: It is not working perfectly it keeps showing the Val(CTcash.text) at Change.CLchange.Caption idk why? I have tried this code before but i change it
(```bill = Val(CTcash.text) - Val(CLtotaloutput.Caption)```)

Comment: What exactly is it no showing correctly?  Could it be an issue with the formatting?  I am getting weird looking formatting but correct answers when testing.

Comment: Val(CTcash.text) here is the money input, Change.CLchange.Caption it is the change for the money input. When i was trying it , Change.CLchange.Caption keeps showing the same value as the Val(CTcash.text). The format is for the Indonesian currency.

Comment: What is `CLtotaloutput.Caption`?  Check that it is being converted correctly.  Does it have a letter in front like `$123` or `Rp 123`?  In this case, `Val` will return 0 no matter what number there is.

Comment: Hmmm I Format CLtotaloutput.Caption to "Rp\. ###,###,###.-". I think it is the problem

Comment: Yes, you need to remove `Rp\. `.  Try `Right(CLtotaloutput.Caption, Len(CLtotaloutput.Caption") - Len("Rp\. "))`

Comment: Use constants for the hardcoded text to make it easier.

Comment: How about the tail of it. It has .- at the back and how about the , at the middle of the currency

Comment: Tail won't matter to `Val` but `,` will.

Comment: You might want to jus strip all non-numerical values from the string.  I'll add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

At first I miss the const, i put it in the other sub:

```
Private Sub CTcash_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 13 Then
        bill = Val(CTcash.Text) - totalsum
        Select Case True
            Case bill > 0
               Change.CLchange.Caption = Format(bill, "Rp\. ###,###,###.-")
               Change.Show
            Case bill < 0
               MsgBox "Not Enough Money", vbOKOnly, "Invalid"
            Case Else
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub CTbarcode_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case Is = vbKeyF6
            totaldiscount = 200
            totalsum = Val(CLsuboutput.Caption) - totaldiscount
            CLtotaloutput.Caption = Format(totalsum, "Rp\. ###,###,###. ,-")
            CLdiscoutput.Caption = Format(totaldiscount, "Rp\. ###,###,###. ,-")
            CTcash.Enabled = True
            CTcash.SetFocus
    End Select
End Sub
```

Here is it after i edit it:

```
Private Sub CTcash_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 13 Then
        totaldiscount = 200
        totalsum = Val(CLsuboutput.Caption) - totaldiscount
        bill = Val(CTcash.Text) - totalsum
        Select Case True
            Case bill > 0
               Change.CLchange.Caption = Format(bill, "Rp\. ###,###,###.-")
               Change.Show
            Case bill < 0
               MsgBox "Not Enough Money", vbOKOnly, "Invalid"
            Case Else
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```